# ASP.NET Cache contains solution path

Tags: asp.net, webforms, outputcache

Why does my Cache object contain a single entry containing the following? Shouldn't it be empty? And if not, obviously there is this ugly default value in the Cache object...how do I remove it? I haven't added anything to the Cache object, yet it contains this item below.

```
__System.Web.WebPages.Deployment__C:\Users\Danny\Documents\Visual Studio  2010\Projects\LearningAOP\WebAppCachingII\WebAppCachingII\***C:\Users\Danny\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LearningAOP\WebAppCachingII\WebAppCachingII\
```

Here is my ASP.NET code-behind, the markup has a single bulleted list control;

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebAppCachingII
{
    public partial class CachingDemo : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry cacheditem in Cache)
            {
                var concatstring = cacheditem.Key + "***" + cacheditem.Value;
                listOfCacheItems.Items.Add(new ListItem(concatstring));
            }
        }
    }
}

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CachingDemo.aspx.cs"     Inherits="WebAppCachingII.CachingDemo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:BulletedList ID="listOfCacheItems" runat="server" />   </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      <caching>
           <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
      </caching> 
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have an `<outputCache />` element in `web.config`?

Comment: No I do not, should I googel that?